# Pointer arithmetic in action

Tags: c++

I have such code

```
for(DWORD i = 0 ; i < dwInBuffSize/8 ; i++)
        DES.des_ecb_encrypt((des_cblock *)InBuff+i, (des_cblock *)OutBuff+i, sched, DES_DECRYPT) ;
```

where

```
typedef unsigned char des_cblock[8];
```

I believe due to pointer arithmetic here:

```
(des_cblock *)InBuff+i
```

pointer is advanced by 8 bytes? instead of 1?

`inBuff` is just byte array as well as `outBuff`.

Comment: If you are writing C++ code for security, *do not* use C-style casts.  Use `static_cast` and friends.

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you know that for any array *or* pointer `p` and integer `i` the expression `*(p + i)` is equivalent to `p[i]`., which means that `p + i` is equivalent to `&p[i]`.

Comment: DES is only appropriate for compatibility with existing use, for playing or when weak security is desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you do `(T*)someptr+x`, then the `x` is multiplied by the `sizeof(T)`.

The same applies for `static_cast<T*>(somepttr)+x` of course, which is alos easier to see that the cast happens before `x` is added.

Comment: so in this case it is 8 bytes?

Comment: In this case `sizeof(des_cblock)`, which appears to be 8, yes.

Comment: So it basically operates on each 8 byte block separately?

Comment: Yes, that would seem to be the case. There's obviously nothing from the posted code saying that the call to `des_ecb_encrypt` doesn't use offsets from the passed in pointer that are less than 0 or greater than 7 - but it certainly gets called once per 8 bytes.